# php script sometimes receives post data sometimes not. It seems a cache problem

Tags: php

I am submitting post data from a HTML form (using javascript to validate the form) to a php script

Several hours ago I realized I was sending empty data so I fixed this problem and now I am still not receiving the post data in the server side even though I am sending it.

When I echo the post variables on the server side I can see the variables echoed when I remove the echo it keeps telling me "No login information". I tried to comment/uncomment the echo several times and it keeps showing the same problem. It seems some kind of cache.

I tried to disable cache using clearstatcache(); and

```
header("Content-Type: text/html");

header("Expires: 0");

header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");

header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);

header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

It does not work. Maybe it is some kind of cache from the html form side, apparently it keeps sending the wrong (empty) data.

When I remove the "no login information" part, it tells me "user does not exist" as when the login info is really missing.

I need to add that this code has been working well for years. I did not change it , besides the first lines for preventing to cache (but this was after the problem appeared). The new code was the html form which is calling this php code.
Part of php code follows

```
<?php
clearstatcache();
header("Content-Type: text/html");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
include("conexion/conexion.php");

//$form_password=$_GET['form_password'];
//$form_email=$_GET['form_email'];
$form_password=$_POST['form_password'];
$form_email=$_POST['form_email'];

//echo "form_password=$form_password";
//echo "form_email=$form_email";



function autentificar(){

 global $form_email,$form_password;

 echo "form_password=$form_password";
 echo "form_email=$form_email";

 //exit();
 $mensaje=1;

if($form_email=='' || $form_password=='')
{
    $mensaje="No login information";
    //echo "form_password=$form_password";
    //echo "form_email=$form_email";
}
else
{
    $con=openDB();
    if(!$con)
   {
       $mensaje="Database connection not opened";
       //exit();
    }
    else
    {

 $query="SELECT USERCODE,NAME,AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(PASSWORD),UNHEX(SHA2('xxxxx',512))) ,USERTYPE,BALANCE,ACTIVELESSONSTATUS,ACTIVELESSONCODEVAR FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL='$form_email'";

 //echo "query=$query";
 //exit();
 //$query="SELECT * FROM usuario ";
 $resultado=genesis_exec($con,$query);
 //$resultado=mysql_query($query,$con);


 if(!$resultado)
 {
     $mensaje="Error en la sentencia SQL";
     echo "Sentencia: $query <br>";
     echo "Error: ".mysql_error();
     closeDB($con);
     exit();
 }
 else
 {
     $fila=genesis_fetch_row($resultado);

     if(!$fila)
     {
        $mensaje="User does not exist";
     }
     else
     {
        $user=genesis_result($resultado,1);
        $name=genesis_result($resultado,2);
        $p=genesis_result($resultado,3);
        $type=genesis_result($resultado,4);
        $balance=genesis_result($resultado,5);
        $status=genesis_result($resultado,6);
        $lesson=genesis_result($resultado,7);
        if($p!=$form_password)
        {
           $mensaje="Incorrect password";

           /*echo "user=$user";
           echo "name=$name";
           echo "p=$p";
            echo "type=$type";

           echo "$mensaje";
           exit();*/
        }
        else
        {
             //AQUI ABRE LA SESION
             //para abrir sesion y usar Header no se debe haber hecho ninguna salida
             session_start();                   //aqui se abre la sesion por primera vez
             $SESION=session_id();

             $query="UPDATE USERS SET SESSIONID='$SESION' WHERE USERCODE='$user'";
             $resultado=genesis_exec($con,$query);
             //Aqui registra las variables de sesion
             $_SESSION['TIPO_USUARIO']=$type;       //usar esto si register_globals=off
            $_SESSION['COD_USUARIO']=$user;                 //usar esto si register_globals=off
            $_SESSION['NOMBRE_USUARIO']=$name;
            $_SESSION['BALANCE']=$balance;
            $_SESSION['ACTIVE_LESSONSTATUS']=$status;
            $_SESSION['LESSON_CODEVAR']=$lesson;
             $mensaje=1;      //solo devuelve 1 si el usuario se autentificó con éxito
            if($pagina=="" && $type=="STUDENT") $pagina="lesson.htm";  //valor por defecto
            if($pagina=="" && $type!="STUDENT") $pagina="opportunities.htm";  //valor por defecto

            }
         }
      }
     genesis_commit($con);
     closeDB($con);
   }

  }

return $mensaje;
}//fin autentificar()
```

part of the client side code follows

```
<form id="sky-form" class="sky-form" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" action="login.php">
            <header>Login form</header>

            <fieldset>                  
                <section>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="label col col-4">E-mail</label>
                        <div class="col col-8">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-user"></i>
                                <input type="email" name="form_email" id="form_email">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="label col col-4">Password</label>
                        <div class="col col-8">
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append icon-lock"></i>
                                <input type="password" name="form_password" id="form_password">
                            </label>
                            <div class="note"><a href="#sky-form2" class="modal-opener">Forgot password?</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <!--
                <section>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-4"></div>
                        <div class="col col-8">
                            <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" checked><i></i>Keep me logged in</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                -->
            </fieldset>
            <footer>
                <div class="fright">
                <a href="register.html" class="button button-secondary">Register</a>
                <button type="submit" class="button">Log in</button>
                </div>

            </footer>
        </form>
```

and the validation function is following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
  //alert('validate');
  if(document.getElementById("form_email").value=='')
  {
    alert('Enter the email');
    return false;
  }  

  if(document.getElementById("form_password").value=='')
  {
    alert('Enter the password');
    return false;
  }
  //alert(document.getElementById("form_email").value);
  //alert(document.getElementById("form_password").value);
  return true;
}
</script>
```

I need to say that all started when in fact I was not sending the data due to an issue with the form and javascript. But I am confident now I am sending the data Because when I echo the post data in the server side it shows the data when I do not echo the data it says "no login information"

IMPORTANT UPDATE: I deleted the file login.php from server and I am still getting the message "No login information" from server.  What is going on ? Please help

Comment: I can't think of any thing that would be caching your POST data between your HTML form and your PHP script. I suspect there's an error with the rest of your PHP and you're erroneously printing `No login information` despite actually having login information. Could you [edit] your question to include more of your PHP script (at the very least, the entirety of `authentificar()`)?

Comment: I added more information/code, thanks

Comment: UPDATE: I deleted the file login.php from server and I am still getting the message "No login information" from server.  What is going on ? Please help

Comment: The PHP script in its entirety looks reasonable. I don't see a way that you'd get "No login information" if the form submission was successful. But it sounds like you're past that at this point. If you've _deleted_ login.php and you're still getting the message... you're missing something significant. and unfortunately, without that critical piece to the puzzle, we aren't going to be able to help :(. If I were you, I would check that the webserver settings are correct, and figure out if the webserver is using `/var/web/login.php`, but you deleted `/home/me/web/login.php` (or whatever)

Comment: Thanks for trying. I merged both files in one single file And it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to merge both files in one single file and it works now